# Is there a way to monitor what processes or programs might be editing the web.config?

Tags: windows, iis, recycle

I have an issue on one of my servers where we are having recycling happening that is not planned. Further inspection results in the following errors:

---

```
Event: Application End
Process ID: 8716

Shut Down Message: HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
HostingEnvironment caused shutdown

Shut Down Stack:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownWithoutDemand()
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.StopProcessing()
```

---

```
Shut Down Message: CONFIG change
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
CONFIG change
HostingEnvironment caused shutdown
Change in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\appserver\347d6bd9\aed72866\hash\hash.web

Shut Down Stack:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownWithoutDemand()
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ShutdownAppDomain(String stackTrace)
   at System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.OnConfigurationChanged(Object sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.OnConfigChanged(InternalConfigEventArgs e)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.OnStreamChanged(String streamname)
   at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationHostFileChange.OnFileChanged(Object sender, FileChangeEvent e)
   at System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.FireNotifications()
   at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.CallCallbackWithAssert(WorkItemCallback callback)
   at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.OnQueueUserWorkItemCompletion(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

---

```
Shut Down Message: CONFIG change
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
CONFIG change
HostingEnvironment caused shutdown
Change in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\appserver\347d6bd9\aed72866\hash\hash.web

Shut Down Stack:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownWithoutDemand()
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ShutdownAppDomain(String stackTrace)
   at System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.OnConfigurationChanged(Object sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.OnConfigChanged(InternalConfigEventArgs e)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.OnStreamChanged(String streamname)
   at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationHostFileChange.OnFileChanged(Object sender, FileChangeEvent e)
   at System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.FireNotifications()
   at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.CallCallbackWithAssert(WorkItemCallback callback)
   at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.OnQueueUserWorkItemCompletion(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

---

The issue we are seeing appears to be that something is editing the web.config file and prompting the recycling to occur. Is there a good way to monitor the config file and see what process or piece of software or potentially user is editing that file?

Thanks,
ThatOneGuy

Comment: What leads you to believe the config file is being edited?

Comment: I added the other error messages that I saw that led me to that conclusion.

Comment: If you have RDP access check out ProcMon: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: Do you have any antivirus software ?

Comment: We do but we had them completely disabled for a time and the issue still continued.